# Cross apply not working in SQL Server 2005

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2005

I have a cross apply code that is working perfectly in SQL Server version 2008 but unfortunately the same code is not working in SQL Server version 2005. Below is the code:

```
SELECT YT.ID,
       YT.Product
       V.C AS Flag
FROM YourTable YT
     CROSS APPLY (VALUES('A'),('B'),('C')) V(C);
```

In SQLServer 2005 version getting error at `values` part

Error:

```
Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Procedure SP_xxx, Line 69
Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'Values'.
```

Not sure what went wrong.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Table value constructors](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/table-value-constructor-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) were introduced in 2008 if i'm not mistaken

Here is a method with [UNION](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/set-operators-union-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017)

```
select *
from (select 1 as a) a
cross apply (select 'A' as X union select 'B' union select 'C') x
```

Or a [CTE](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/with-common-table-expression-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017)

```
with cte as(
select 'A' as X union select 'B' union select 'C')

select *
from (select 1 as a) a
cross apply cte
```

Heads up though, [SQL Server 2005 support ended in 2016.](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/sql-server/sql-server-2005) So, now would be a good time to try and upgrade :)